# (XAMARIN ANDROID) - How can I for each loop through a List<T> and grab each item then pass to a array adapter then to a listview

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.android, repository

Heres my sample code for getting the values from API :

My Class Info (Models)

```
 public class COUNTRESULT_Info
{

public  decimal STDSKU { get; set; }

public  decimal STDQTC { get; set; }

public  string CSTSDS { get; set; }

public  string STDDSC { get; set; }


}
```

My repository for API :

```
 public async Task<List<T>> GetCountResult(string trfnumber, string usertype) {

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://hoscbdd1:8888/api/result/GETCOUNTRESULT/"+trfnumber+"/"+usertype);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

    }

}
```

Activity FOR ANDROID (THROUGH LIST VIEW):

```
   private async void GetCountResult(string trfnumber, string usertype) {

        ResultRepository<COUNTRESULT_Info> repo = new ResultRepository<COUNTRESULT_Info>();

        var result = await repo.GetCountResult(trfnumber, usertype);

        if (result != null)
        {
            stringResult = result.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, stringResult);
            listview_countresult.Adapter = adapter;
        }
    }
```

The output in my listview is it counts how many objects Found like:

SCRS.MODEL.COUNTRESULT_Info

SCRS.MODEL.COUNTRESULT_Info

SCRS.MODEL.COUNTRESULT_Info

SCRS.MODEL.COUNTRESULT_Info

SCRS.MODEL.COUNTRESULT_Info

Comment: What exactly do you want here your question is quite unclear

Comment: @G.hakim i just want  my output will be each item of class info to be inputted in one row in list view.

Comment: You want all of it in one row?

Comment: Yes @G.hakim . In one list view item, one  data from count result info are included

Comment: @Andrespengineer i tried already the error comes out , cannot convert generic list to int.

Comment: Try: remove `.ToString()` from Linq; `stringResult = result.Select(x => x).ToList();` and `new ArrayAdapter<COUNTRESULT_Info>(..., stringResult);` the result of that should be a LisView of `COUNTRESULT_Info` objects. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you're doing a `ToString()` on each `COUNTRESULT_Info` returned from your `repo.GetCountResult`:

```
stringResult = result.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

In other words, this is what you're doing: `COUNTRESULT_Info.ToString()`

You *already* have a `List<COUNTRESULT_Info>` returned from your repo method, so you can obtain any of it's properties - e.g. `x.CSTSDS` or `x.STDQTC.ToString()`

Hth..

Comment: Ill be using foreach to get each value in result. then passed it onto a list of string or array? because if im passing it to the array adapter for list view the last parameter should be int.

Comment: @RavenSupilanas No idea what you're after...see the answer below for how to move forward to what you're going for...

Answer (score 1):

Well, my understanding of your question leads me to something like this :

```
  if (result != null)
    {
       stringResult= new List<string>();
       foreach(var item in result)
       {
          string s= item.STDSKU.toString() + item.STDQTC.toString() + item.CSTSDS +item.STDDSC
          stringResult.Add(s);
       }            
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, stringResult);
        listview_countresult.Adapter = adapter;
    }
```